# Load dynamic SCSS file with Rails + Webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, webpack-dev-server, ruby-on-rails-5.1, sass-loader

I'm using the gem [rails/webpack](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) to build the assets, but I need build a dynamic SCSS according by a brand, like:

```
//admin.scss
@import 'variables-<%= 'brand-name' %>';

body {
   background: $primary-color;
}
```

I have tried adding the loader:

```
{
  test: /\.scss(\.erb)?/,
  loader: 'sass-loader',
  options: { importExtensions: ['.scss', '.scss.erb', '.css'] }
}
```

but that didn't work.
Is there a way to do something like that?

Comment: Webpack will not run assets through the ERB interpreter - Sprockets however does. You also need to be aware that assets are usually compiled at deploy time so any variable cannot be request based. A better solution may be to use classes in your HTML to set different rules in the stylesheet to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in a separate controller action:

layout.html.erb

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag stylesheet_path() %>`

Stylesheet show controller action

```
# Render the template to a string
css = Sass::Engine.new(
  render_to_string("path/to/erb_template", :layout => false),
  syntax:     :scss,
  cache:      false,
  read_cache: false,
  style:      :standard,
  sprockets:  {
    context:     self.view_context,
  }
).render

# respond with the rendered string
respond_to do |format|
  format.css { render plain: css, :content_type => "text/css" }
end
```

You can then include the ERB variables in the template. Note that this will be put through the sass engine on every single load so you will want to cache this on production.

If you want to keep all your sass nicely organised into separate files just put your variables in one file to render as ERB and the rest just read in as text files.

```
rendered_sass = [render_to_string("stylesheets/colours", :layout => false),
  File.read(Rails.root.join("app", "javascript", "stylesheets", "main.scss")),
  File.read(Rails.root.join("app", "javascript", "stylesheets", "base.scss")),
  File.read(Rails.root.join("app", "javascript", "stylesheets", "reset.scss")),
  File.read(Rails.root.join("app", "javascript", "stylesheets", "type.scss")),
  File.read(Rails.root.join("app", "javascript", "stylesheets", "layout.scss")),
  File.read(Rails.root.join("app", "javascript", "stylesheets", "map.scss")),
  File.read(Rails.root.join("app", "javascript", "stylesheets", "audio-player.scss")),
  File.read(Rails.root.join("app", "javascript", "stylesheets", "slider.scss"))].join("\n\r")
```

Comment: wow, what a solution :) maybe I try it, but for now, I create a single .scss file to each company and at the layout, I import them: ```<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'login-' + @company.sub_domain %>```
not the best solution, but It solved partially my problem.

Comment: You will soon run into scaling issues when you get more than a handful of clients ;-). The above technique doesn't take a lot of time to implement once you start. But yeah - this is quite a nice way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

variable in rails app :

```
module Constants
  COLORS = {
     COLOR1: '#ff0000',
     COLOR2: '#880000',
  }
end
```

pass to sass with Hash var :

```
$colors: (<% Constants::COLORS.each do |name, color| %><%= name %>: <%= color %>,<% end %>)
```

use variable in ur style file :

```
body
  color: map-get($colors, 'COLOR1')
```